# Java: data synchronization issue

Tags: java, volatile, data-synchronization

My Java program makes a request to client's API and client's API will return a key-value pair on **irregular** time intervals (i.e. not every 5 seconds / 10 seconds, sometimes 1 second or 5 seconds).

And I have inserted my own code which is a `HashMap`, into the client API code to store all the key-value pairs.

My goal is run the below code marked with "!!!" as soon as the Hashmap conditions are matched.
I am not an expert in Java data synchronization. Note that `Thread.Sleep(3000)` would not work, as the key-value pairs are updated on irregular time intervals. Moreover, the value of the same key will also change over time.
I tried the run the program below and it immediately ran through the block of code marked with "!!!", which is not what I want to achieve.

What is the most efficient solution to tackle this problem ?

```
Class Testing{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        // connect to API...
        ClientAPI clientAPI = new ClientAPI();
        clientAPI.connect();

        // make a request to retrieve an update of a HashMap
        clientAPI.requestHashMapUpdate();

        // !!! execute the following block of code only if hashmap contains a specific key value pair, i.e. key1, 1 
        // if hashmap does not contain key or the key-value pair do not match , then wait until the key-value pair are matched and run the code
        if(clientAPI.getMyHashMap().containsKey("key1")){
            if(clientAPI.getMyHashMap().get("key1") == 1){
                    System.out.println("Print Me only if key and value are matched !!!!!!!!");
            }
        }

    }
}


Class ClientAPI{
    private HashMap<String,Integer> myHashMap;
    
    // Constructor
    public clientAPI(){
            myHashMap = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
    }

    // callback function of API's requestHashMapUpdate method
    public void updateHashMapKeyValuePair(String key, int value){
        System.out.println("Key:" + key + ", Value: " + value);
        // code i wrote to update hashmap with key value pair returned from API
        myHashMap.put(key,value);
    }

    // my code to retrieve the latest snapshot of myHashMap
    public HashMap<String,Integer> getMyHashMap(){
        return myHashMap;
    }

}
```

Comment: There isn't really very much you can do other than check the contents of the HashMap every time it is updated. If you can't be notified when it is updated, there isn't really very much you can do other than poll.

Comment: Is there a way to  notify the program then when the hashmap is updated?

Comment: Not inherently. Just notify clients from the code where you update the map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override your client API (if it is not closed to extends):

```
class MyClientAPI extends ClientAPI {
    ...
    @Override
    public void updateHashMapKeyValuePair(String key, int value) {
        super.updateHashMapKeyValuePair(key, value);
        if("key1".equals(key) && 1 == value)
            System.out.println("Print Me only if key and value are matched !!!!!!!!");
    }
    ...
}
```

and simply check each new value that comes in.

To use it, only change

```
ClientAPI clientAPI = new MyClientAPI();
```

Another way to solve this is to provide your `ClientAPI` class with the ability to register listeners

```
interface UpdateHashMapKeyValuePairListener {
    void digestUpdate(String key, int value);
}

class ClientAPI {
    ...
    private List<UpdateHashMapKeyValuePairListener> listeners = new ArrayList();
    ...
    public void registerUpdateListener(UpdateHashMapKeyValuePairListener u) {
        listeners.add(u);
    }
    ...
    public void updateHashMapKeyValuePair(final String key, final int value) {
        listeners.forEach(u -> u.digestUpdate(key, value));
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

then, anyone who wants to know when a new value enters, just implement this interface, e.g.

```
...
clientAPI.registerUpdateListener((key, value) -> {
    if("key1".equals(key) && 1 == value)
        System.out.println("Print Me only if key and value are matched !!!!!!!!");
});
clientAPI.connect();
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the contents of the HashMap every time it is updated. To achieve this, you can register a listener in `Testing` class to be triggered every time the `HashMap` is updated in `ClientAPI` class.

First define the functional interface for the listener:

```
 @FunctionalInterface
  public interface OnUpdateMapListener {
      void onUpdateMap(Map<String, Integer> map);
  }
```

then add the listener in the `ClientAPI`

```
 public class ClientAPI {
        private HashMap<String, Integer> myHashMap;
        private OnUpdateMapListener onUpdateMapListener;
```

Define `onMapUpdate` method to pass the listener's body in `ClientAPI`:

```
public void onMapUpdate(OnUpdateMapListener onUpdateMapListener) {
        this.onUpdateMapListener = onUpdateMapListener;
}
```

and trigger the listener upon HashMap update in `updateHashMapKeyValuePair`

```
public void updateHashMapKeyValuePair(String key, int value) {
  System.out.println("Key:" + key + ", Value: " + value);
  // code i wrote to update hashmap with key value pair returned from API
   myHashMap.put(key, value);
   onUpdateMapListener.onUpdateMap(myHashMap);
 }
```

In the main method register the listener and check the map contents. This will be triggered every time the `ClientAPI` receives new Map contents in `updateHashMapKeyValuePair` method:

```
clientAPI.onMapUpdate(stringIntegerHashMap -> {
      // !!! the following code is executed every time the hashMap is updated
       if (clientAPI.getMyHashMap().containsKey("key1")) {
           if (clientAPI.getMyHashMap().get("key1") == 1) {
             System.out.println("Print Me only if key and value are matched !!!!!!!!");
           }
      }
});
```

`ClientAPI`  class:

```
public class ClientAPI {
    private HashMap<String, Integer> myHashMap;

    private OnUpdateMapListener onUpdateMapListener;

    // Constructor
    public ClientAPI() {
        myHashMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    }

    // callback function of API's requestHashMapUpdate method
    public void updateHashMapKeyValuePair(String key, int value) {
        System.out.println("Key:" + key + ", Value: " + value);
        // code i wrote to update hashmap with key value pair returned from API
        myHashMap.put(key, value);
        onUpdateMapListener.onUpdateMap(myHashMap);
    }

    // my code to retrieve the latest snapshot of myHashMap
    public HashMap<String, Integer> getMyHashMap() {
        return myHashMap;
    }

    public void requestHashMapUpdate() {
      //.....
    }

    public void onMapUpdate(OnUpdateMapListener onUpdateMapListener) {
        this.onUpdateMapListener = onUpdateMapListener;
    }
}
```

`Testing` class:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
      // connect to API...
        ClientAPI clientAPI = new ClientAPI();
        clientAPI.connect();

        // make a request to retrieve an update of a HashMap
       clientAPI.requestHashMapUpdate();

        clientAPI.onMapUpdate(stringIntegerHashMap -> {
            // !!! the following code is executed every time the hashMap is updated
            if (clientAPI.getMyHashMap().containsKey("key1")) {
                if (clientAPI.getMyHashMap().get("key1") == 1) {
                    System.out.println("Print Me only if key and value are matched !!!!!!!!");
                }
            }
        });

        clientAPI.updateHashMapKeyValuePair("key1", 1);
        clientAPI.updateHashMapKeyValuePair("key1", 2);
    }
```

Results:

```
Key:key1, Value: 1
Print Me only if key and value are matched !!!!!!!!
Key:key1, Value: 2
```